# Auto generate documentation from tests (javascript, jest)

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs, documentation

I want to generate documentation that depends on tests. For example, I have a file with tests:

```js
describe("sum", () => {
  it("sums 1 and 2", () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toEqual(3);
  });
  it("sums 3 and 4", () => {
    expect(sum(3, 4)).toEqual(7);
  });
});

describe("multiplication", () => {
  it("multiply 10 and 20", () => {
    expect(multiplication(10, 20)).toEqual(200);
  });
  it("multiply 30 and 40", () => {
    expect(multiplication(30, 40)).toEqual(1200);
  });
});
```

And depends on that file I want to receive something like a comment at top of this test file (summary):

```
// Index test cases

// sum
// - [x] sums 1 and 2
// - [x] sums 3 and 4

// multiplication
// - [x] multiply 10 and 20
// - [x] multiply 30 and 40

describe("sum", () => {
  it("sums 1 and 2", () => {
    expect(sum(1, 2)).toEqual(3);
  });
  it("sums 3 and 4", () => {
    expect(sum(3, 4)).toEqual(7);
  });
});

describe("multiplication", () => {
  it("multiply 10 and 20", () => {
    expect(multiplication(10, 20)).toEqual(200);
  });
  it("multiply 30 and 40", () => {
    expect(multiplication(30, 40)).toEqual(1200);
  });
});
```

And a markdown file that I can publish to GitHub Wiki:

```
# Index test cases

## sum
 - [x] sums 1 and 2
 - [x] sums 3 and 4

## multiplication
 - [x] multiply 10 and 20
 - [x] multiply 30 and 40
```

Maybe there are best practices to do such things or ready to use packages?
Maybe I should use JSDoc?
The main thing is to create "summary" and not read hundreds lines of tests.

Workflow can be:

`write tests => run generateDocs.js => summary adds at top of file and markdown file creates`

Created a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/documentation-from-tests-u9n3z

Comment: what do you mean by running generateDocs.js, if I need to get the markdown file?